# Line Break in AJAX Callback

Tags: jquery, ajax, callback

I have a simple script to get a value from PHP:

```
function getLanguage(callback)
{
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "/language.php",
        type:'POST',
        success: function(result){
            callback(result);
        },
    });
}
```

I then use that function elsewhere in my file:

```
var localeString;
getLanguage(function(returnedData){

   localeString = returnedData;

});
```

Here is the PHP content:

```
session_start();
$currentLanguage = $_SESSION['Language'];
echo $currentLanguage;
```

The issue that I'm having is that the variable `localeString` has a new line in it somehow.  For example, if I do this:

```
alert(localeString+"goes here");
```

The output I get is:

```
en
goes here
```

I've validated that the PHP code is returning the value only but can't figure out why I'm getting he line break.

Thank you!

Comment: How are we supposed to tell why the PHP code *you haven't shown us* is outputting a line break? (Although it is probably just that you have a line break at the end of the file).

Comment: @Quentin  Just updated with the PHP code.

Comment: Still betting that in the PHP code you didn't include (you've included some, but not all of it), you have a new line. (After a `?>` probably).

Comment: Yes - you were right.  There was an extra line in the PHP file.  That fixed the issue.  Thank you for the help!